# shell_excec() does not return MySQL result formatted

Tags: php, mysql, bash, shell, formatting

I wanted to make my life easier, so I tried to make the standard command line command to format mysql results for me.

```
$query = "select name from accounts limit 10";
$cmd = "mysql -u$user -p$pw -e \"$query\" $db_name";
$ret = shell_exec($cmd);
echo $ret;
```

but the result I get is

```
name
3+kk, s.r.o.
3CLogic. Inc
3ok s.r.o.
3P Consulting, s.r.o.
3xlab
4profit, s.r.o.
A C T I V A
A test acc
A4B, a.s.
AB Trade Europe s.r.o.
```

Instead of a formatted command line output

```
+------------------------+
| name                   |
+------------------------+
| 3+kk, s.r.o.           |
| 3CLogic. Inc           |
| 3ok s.r.o.             |
| 3P Consulting, s.r.o.  |
| 3xlab                  |
| 4profit, s.r.o.        |
| A C T I V A            |
| A test acc             |
| A4B, a.s.              |
| AB Trade Europe s.r.o. |
+------------------------+
```

How can I make the shell_exec() function to return the formatted form?

Comment: Why do this in shell?

Comment: I see no difference in the format/layout you get from either outputs. Do you want the grid along with the results from the database? If so. Thays going to be more effort than what it is worth to process the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the output from the mysql command piped to a other cmd ie. your application mysql client strips this information you can turn it on wit the **-t** option.

**sample**

**normal output**

```
$ mysql -uroot -e "select * from l.user_art"
+----+---------+--------+
| id | user_id | art_id |
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 |      10 |     10 |
|  2 |      20 |     30 |
|  3 |      20 |     80 |
|  4 |      10 |     90 |
|  5 |      20 |     10 |
|  6 |      23 |     10 |
|  7 |      23 |     11 |
|  8 |      23 |     12 |
|  9 |      10 |     11 |
+----+---------+--------+
```

**output piped in other cmd (cat)**

```
$ mysql -uroot -e "select * from l.user_art" | cat
id      user_id art_id
1       10      10
2       20      30
3       20      80
4       10      90
5       20      10
6       23      10
7       23      11
8       23      12
9       10      11
```

**piped output with optin -t**

```
$ mysql -uroot -t -e "select * from l.user_art" | cat
+----+---------+--------+
| id | user_id | art_id |
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 |      10 |     10 |
|  2 |      20 |     30 |
|  3 |      20 |     80 |
|  4 |      10 |     90 |
|  5 |      20 |     10 |
|  6 |      23 |     10 |
|  7 |      23 |     11 |
|  8 |      23 |     12 |
|  9 |      10 |     11 |
+----+---------+--------+
```